# sketching semicirles and horizontal lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, multline, parallel

I want to sketch this parallel lines and semicircles between them sth like the attached figure[image: propagation of wave in to the layers of earth]...
would you plz help me?

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: actually I can oly draw parallel lines but I cant draw semicircles between them...I dont want to draw this graphic with other programs like Microsoft office or paint etc because I am typing my thesis with latex and it is better to have my graphics drawn by it too. I would so grateful if you can guide me.

Comment: Are the circular arcs supposed to have common centres?  If so wouldn't the down arrows be straight lines?

Comment: You can do this sort of diagram in Metapost, or Asymptote, or Tikz easily enough, but you just need to pick one and read the manuals!

Comment: yes the circular arcs have the common center... If i learn how to draw one of this arcs i will be able to draw the rest...But unfortunately I am amateur! :(

Comment: @hamed The `tikz` manual has numerous example of arcs and curves, a good table of contents and a reasonably comprehensive index. This site features numerous similar arcs and curves. Metapost is also well documented and there are libraries of example for both `tikz` and metapost online. (Can't say about `asymptote`.) Right now you are basically saying that you want somebody to do it for you because you cannot be bothered!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another (possibly better) complete solution using `intersections` and `calc` libraries with the aid of a `\foreach` construct can be as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning,intersections}
\begin{document}
\def\dis{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.7pt,>=latex',node distance=\dis]
\node (o) at (0*\dis,8*\dis) {$\ast$};
\path [draw,name path=bigarc1, bend right=10,->,shorten >=10pt](o.center)to([xshift=2.5*\dis,yshift=-7*\dis]o);
\path [draw,name path=bigarc2, bend left=10,->,shorten >=10pt](o.center)to([xshift=-2.5*\dis,yshift=-7*\dis]o);
\foreach \y/\c in {7/1,6/2,5/3,4/4,3/5,2/6}{
\path [draw,name path=Line-\c] (-3*\dis,\y*\dis)--(3*\dis,\y*\dis) node[right=0.2*\dis]{$V_{\c}$};
\path [name intersections={of = bigarc1 and Line-\c}];
\coordinate (p) at (intersection-1);
\path [name intersections={of = bigarc2 and Line-\c}];
\coordinate (q) at (intersection-1);
\draw [bend left,shorten >=-5pt,shorten <=-5pt](p)to(q);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output of such a code is as expected:

[image]

I completed another solution based on the idea of Sigur as an alternative.

The complete code (following Sigur's idea) is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
\node  (p-0) at (0,0) {$\ast$};
\node  (q-0) at (0,0) {};
\foreach \raft/\rbef in {1/0,2/1,3/2,4/3,5/4,6/5}{
\path [draw, name path global/.expanded =L-\raft](-6,-\raft)--(6,-\raft) node [right] {$V_{\raft}$};
\path [draw, name path global/.expanded =A-\raft,thick] (-120:1.1*\raft) arc (-120:-60:1.1*\raft);
\path [name intersections/.expanded ={of ={L-\raft} and {A-\raft}}];
\coordinate (p-\raft) at (intersection-1);
\coordinate (q-\raft) at (intersection-2);
}
\draw [->,shorten >=-10pt](p-0.center)--(p-1)--(p-2)--(p-3)--(p-4)--(p-5)--(p-6);
\draw [->,shorten >=-10pt](q-0.center)--(q-1)--(q-2)--(q-3)--(q-4)--(q-5)--(q-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output of that code is the following figure:

[image]

But it is slightly different from the required figure in the question.

Comment: thank so much for your favor dear Mr @AboAmmar. It was so useful and I am so glad that I could get my answer as best as possible. I am so interested to learn more about drawing such graphics with latex when I see how beautiful this graphics are made. I learned so many points with your help.

Comment: But these arcs do not have a common center...

Comment: @Thruston-- For equidistant concentric circles, the intersection points with equidistant parallel lines should be aligned to a straight line. This is not the case in the requested picture of the question. If you observe the two long down curves you see what I mean. The two long down-paths may be curves or segments of a straight line, but surely not a straight line.

Comment: We are not racing towards the most accurate, everybody is stating their craziest ideas :) so don't worry too much about correctness. Actually the crazier, the better it gets. Sometimes the crazy answer opens up a whole angle and people build up on it.

Comment: @percusse-- You are absolutely right!! this site is for sharing our ideas in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial solution** (using `tikz`)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$\ast$};
\foreach \r in {1,2,...,6}{
\draw (-6,-\r)--(6,-\r)node[right]{$v_{\r}$};
%\draw (-135:\r) circle (1pt);
\draw[thick] (-135:1.2*\r) arc (-135:-45:1.2*\r);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The syntax for the arc needs the initial point `P` to determine the ray `OP` and then makes use of the second argument which is the initial angle and the final angle and the radius.

[image]

Another image to explain the angles (in polar coordinates `(angle:radius)`):

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly explain the syntax of `(-135:1.2*\r) arc (-135:-45:1.2*\r)`? Not the `\r` bit but the specification of the arc. I keep reading the manual on this and I realise that drawing lines is pretty much the most straightforward thing there is but, for whatever reason, I find it almost impossible to understand. (I end up just guessing by trial-and-error which is not very efficient.) I more-or-less understand Metapost's syntax for this, if that helps.

Comment: wooow... its exactly whatever I want... I was able to draw the parallel lines but i could not draw the intersecting arc...thanks so so so much for your help.

Comment: updated to show the angles and polar coordinates. Note that I used 20% bigger radius otherwise the lines would be tangent.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you need only one angle specified for the first point but two fro the second point, though? Why isn't `(-45:1.2*\r)` enough for the second?