# drawing 2-D coordinates with 2 simple line in it

Tags: diagrams, coordinates

I want to draw this coordinates with straight lines in it...
would you do me a favor and help me?[image: least squares description]

Comment: Have a look at [TiKZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) (or a first impression: [Graphics with Tikz](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mertz/mertz.pdf) or [A very minimal introduction to TiKz](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) or [official documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) - credits @dawu's comment yesterday). Can you show us with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), what you have tried until now?

Comment: @Hachbard_C unfortunately I am so amateur and I should type my thesis asp and actually  I do not have enough time to learn new subject, would you do me a favor and help me drawing that?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the image you just posted. It will have some drawbacks compared to an image drawn with e.g. TikZ, but it will undoubtedly be the fastest solution if time is of the essence.

Comment: @Charles Staats the quality of the image is not good and it is better for bueauty of my text to drawing with tikz package... it is not possible for you to draw it?

Comment: Will I get paid for it? Then I'll do it asap for you. But if you want some (free) help, please show some effort (especially considering your question history [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193534/drawing-two-curved-arrows-with-ellipse-between-them), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193444/sketching-simple-arrows-with-different-direction), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196135/drawing-some-simple-circular-rectangular-and-triangular-shapes), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193510/sketching-semicirles-and-horizontal-lines)).

Comment: As I'm running out of characters for a comment: Looking at all of these questions, it would've been more than benefical for you having a look at TikZ!

Comment: @hamed I quote: *I am so amateur and I should type my thesis asp and actually I do not have enough time to learn new subject, would you do me a favor and help me drawing that?* That's not how the site works... Do yourself a favour and read the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @Jobobs thanks a lot... I promise that I will read the manual about the packages and try my best to achieve my answers...

Answer (score 3):

Try this quick solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.7pt,p/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]

\draw (1,0)node[yshift=-1cm]{$\mathcal{R}(A)$} -- (9,0)node[yshift=1cm,left]{$Ax_{1s}$} (5,4)--(5,-4) (1,-2)--(9,2);
\draw [dashed](7,1)node[p]{}--node[right]{$r$} ++(-7mm,14mm)node[p,label=left:$y$]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A free of charge answer with PSTricks. Compile it with `xelatex` for your convenience or with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` for my convenience.

### Option 1

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psline(-5,0)(5,0)
    \psline(0,-5)(0,5)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](5;-150){A}(5;30){B}
    \psline(A)(B)
    \pstGeonode
        [PointName={none,default},PosAngle=180,CurveType=polyline,linestyle=dashed]
        ([nodesep=7]{B}A){temp}([offset=1,nodesep=7]{B}A){y}
    \rput([nodesep=1,offset=1]{B}A){$\mathcal{R}(A)$}
    \rput([nodesep=8,offset=-1]{B}A){$Ax_{1s}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2

Without any package loaded.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psline(-5,0)(5,0)
    \psline(0,-5)(0,5)
    \rput{40}(0,0){%
        \psline(-5,0)(5,0)%
        \qdisk(2,0){2pt}%
        \qdisk(2,1){2pt}%
        \psline[linestyle=dashed](2,0)(2,1)%
        \rput[0]{*0}(2.25,0.5){$r$}%
        \uput[180]{*0}(2,1){$y$}%
    }
    \rput(-4,-2){$\mathcal{R}(A)$}
    \rput(3,1){$Ax_{1s}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]